# Retain dynamically added via Javascript content after PHP postback

Tags: javascript, postback

I have a page that has a button to dynamically add columns to the page as in Figure 1 below. As soon as I use one of my select menu items to do a postback, the columns disappears.

The select menu's are generated using serverside code in php. The columns are generated using Javascript.

[image]

Figure 1 - Column added using Javascript

[image]

Figure 2 - After postback the column disappears

I don't know how to troubleshoot the problem, and what would the best approach be.

I could use AJAX for the select menu's, not sure if that actually solves the issue.